# Sudden crashing and error on previously working python statsmodels code

Tags: python, debugging, numpy, anaconda, statsmodels

I've been running a class that I've coded for classification for the past several days without problems, when all of a sudden Anaconda's Spyder crashed and needed to restart.
Now, on the same code that wasn't previously causing problems, I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\app\anacondasoftware\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py:1327: 
DeprecationWarning: Implicitly casting between incompatible kinds. In a future 
numpy release, this will raise an error. Use casting="unsafe" if this is 
intentional.
  u, s, vt = gufunc(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
```

This error pops up when the program gets to this line of code:

```
    temp_g = sm.WLS(y1, self.X, w).fit()
```

Previously above I've done `import statsmodels.api as sm`

I really don't know what's wrong. After the error, I get a dialog box asking if I want to close the program or debug it. When I choose debug, it says

```
Unhandled exception at 0x1e0ee4fc in python.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
```

Does anyone have any idea of what to do here, or what could have gone wrong? And how and where in my code can I add `casting="unsafe"`, according to the error.

Comment: I guess you got something "weird" in your data. What are your versions of numpy and scipy? Are y1 or self.X or w object arrays? Do you have nans or infs in wexog? The only segfault I've ever seen was with one older version of numpy where using numpy.linalg on datetimes segfaulted. It might be better to move this to the statsmodels issue tracker https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues.

Comment: No the data was the same as the old one. I realized what was wrong - I was using the 32-bit version instead of 64-bit.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the 32-bit version crashes. The 32-bit version isn't supposed to crash either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, after the initial crash, I'd forgotten which Anaconda/Spyder/Python version to run, so I was running the 32-bit version on my 64-bit machine.

When I switched back to the 64-bit version, everything was normal again.